# How to write correct xml for special characters

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I'm trying to write correct svg from string  which uses special characters.I'm using UTF-8 encoding for svg document.I'm working on javascript .
The string is like :

```
<glyph unicode="&#xa5;" horiz-adv-x="819" />
```

While writing xml using DOMParser api , it converts ¥ into ¥ which is incorrect xml and browser throws XML Parsing error .

Here is the complete text which I want to convert into SVG document .

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<metadata></metadata>
  <defs>
    <font id="DearestRegular" horiz-adv-x="2048" >
      <font-face units-per-em="2048" ascent="1638" descent="-410" />
      <glyph unicode="&#xa5;" horiz-adv-x="819" />
    </font>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

Using DOMParser I'm getting the output like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<metadata></metadata>
  <defs>
    <font id="DearestRegular" horiz-adv-x="2048" >
      <font-face units-per-em="2048" ascent="1638" descent="-410" />
      <glyph unicode="¥" horiz-adv-x="819" />
    </font>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

This throws XML Parsing error in browser .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not incorrect XML.

Possibly your server is sending the wrong [character encoding information](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding.en) in the HTTP headers.

(Since the XML declaration doesn't say otherwise,  you should be using UTF-8)

Comment: I'm just using ajax locally with XMLHttpRequest object to read svg file . Here is the code : var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); req.open("GET","Fonts/myFont.svg",true);req.onreadystatechange=function(){if(4 == req.readyState){ var text = req.responseText,dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(text,"image/svg+xml")}} ;req.send(null) ; The doc object I'm getting gives XML parsing error   for the character ¥ .It should have been &#xa5; for correct svg document.